# & operator send nsurl in ios objective c

Tags: objective-c

```
#define BaseURL @"http://oaayush-aayush.rhcloud.com/api/"
#define API_KEY @"1fa448b4c2384c5d0a7a058554964e"


-(void)getMedicineDetailsForID:(NSString *)ID{

    NSString *pathComponent = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"medicine_details/?key=%@&id=%@",API_KEY,ID];
    NSLog(@"%@",ID);
    NSString *requestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",baseURL,pathComponent];

    NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[requestString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [self.session dataTaskWithURL:requestURL  completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

        [self.delegate updateDataSourceWith:[dict valueForKeyPath:@"response"]];
        NSLog(@"%@",[dict valueForKeyPath:@"response"]);

    }];

    [dataTask resume];
}

-(void)getMedicineSuggestionsForID:(NSString *)ID{

    NSString *pathComponent = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"medicine_suggestions/?key=%@&id=%@&limit=200",API_KEY,ID];

    NSString *requestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",baseURL,pathComponent];

    NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[requestString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:requestURL];

    request.timeoutInterval = 15.0;

    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [self.session dataTaskWithRequest:request  completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSError *jsonError;
        NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&jsonError];
        NSInteger statusCode = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode];
        if (error) {
            [self.delegate requestFailedWithError:(int)error.code];
        }
        else if (statusCode != 200) {
            [self.delegate requestFailedWithError:NSURLErrorTimedOut];
        }
        else if (dict){
            [self.delegate updateDataSourceWith:[dict valueForKeyPath:@"response.suggestions"]];
        }

    }];

    [dataTask resume];

}
```

Comment: What's your question ?

Comment: Question is missing the question part.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for `NSURLComponents`